# How do I add httpErrors errormode in config transform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I dont want to have to add this node to the main web.config, I want to insert it via the config transforms.

I tried doing this:

It successfully add the customErrors node but httpErrors throws an error ( the preview transform feature fails).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about add an empty block in the main config file:

```
 <httpErrors>
   </httpErrors>
```

And the replace the block in the release configuration?

```
 <httpErrors xdt:Transform="Replace">
  .........
   </httpErrors>
```

May be it could work. I think it may work.